# Maria DB SQL Insert INTO ON DUPLICATE working only for first updated value

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I am using this http://www.phpzag.com/create-live-editable-table-with-jquery-php-and-mysql/ as a template for editing two columns in my table. The edited entries are saved in new SQL table and called by unique key identifier back.

With each edit where the ID does not exist in the SQL I need the ID to be created so instead just UPDATE:

`UPDATE notes SET $update_field WHERE shop_order='" . $input["SHOP_ORDER_NO"] . "'"`

statement in SQL I want to check if ID exist and if so, to just update edited value otherwise create ID and update value. The update statement above works when ID is created.

Code below update just the "priority" value, not the note when edited. Also when I edit "note" it will not create new ID. I tried to figure it out for half a day without success.

```
<?php

include_once("db_connect.php");

$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
$poznamka = $input['note'];

if ($input['action'] == 'edit') {

    $update_field='';

    if(isset($input["priority"])) {
        $update_field.= "priority='".$input["priority"]."'";
    } else if(isset($input["note"])) {
        $update_field.= "note='".$input["note"]."'";
    }

    if($update_field && $input["SHOP_ORDER_NO"]) {  
        $sql_query = "INSERT INTO notes (shop_order,priority,note) 
        VALUES ('" . $input["SHOP_ORDER_NO"] . "','" . $input["priority"] . "','" . $input["note"] . "')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $update_field ";

        mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query) or die("database error:".mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

That link is missing some things, like a `PRIMARY KEY`.  And IODKU depends on a `UNIQUE` key, which is usually a different column.

Your statement will act on only row, assuming there is only one duplicate value for some `UNIQUE` key.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the generated SQL so we can point out specifics.

Read the online docs about using `... UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` as a kludge for getting the new or old auto_increment id.

If you need to apply IODKU to multiple rows, see the syntax

```
INSERT INTO t (col1, col2, ...)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
    SELECT ((multiple rows from somewhere else));
```

However, this cannot provide the auto_increment ids for each new/existing row.